# How to move the cursor to mouse position while inputting value in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, multitasking

**Windows:**  I am creating a program which is a type of text editor (for learning C). I want to move the cursor to `X and Y of the mouse click position`. While `getche()` is being used. I currently have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    char a;
    do{
           a=getche();
           fflush(stdin);
           printf("%c");
    }while(a!=13)
}
```

where 13 is the Enter key in ASCII.

Have a look at this image:

[image: Have a look at this image]

**Here I want that whenever I press inside the console, the cursor jumps to it's position.**

I have heard that it can be done with threads. But i really don't know how. I searched a lot on the internet but I never found anything helpful.

**Note : I am using GCC compiler (Code Blocks)**

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. Do you want the blinking text cursor to move to your mouse cursor when you click ? If that's so, I don't see the point of monitoring the keyboard input for the Enter key... What you need to do is a Windows event callback to catch the mouseClick event on your window and you certainly don't need any multithreading for this.

Comment: Looks like Microsoft Windows. In general, you might not have windows or a mouse (e.g. when connected to a Linux server via SSH).

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming Microsoft Windows)

You'll have to read the mouse events via [`ReadConsoleInput()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685035(v=vs.85).aspx) and then set the cursor position via `SetConsoleCursorPosition`.

Answer (score 0):

In turbo c I used to use interrupt routine by defining x86 interrupts. you can try using that.

It can give you input for any interrupts, including mouse on press and on release, and location of where the mouse presently is. But you have to first understand x86 interrupts in C to use them.

Sorry don't have an example with me right now.

Suggestion: Also if you want to imitate a text editor, you should also allow movement through arrows and when you use a=getche() it'll print and also give u input in a and you then are using printf("%c") without any var, it's actually not required.